# class constexpr expressions in initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, initialization-list

The following code fails to link with g++ 4.8.2:

```
#include <map>

struct Foo
{
    constexpr static int foo = 1;
};

static std::map<int, int> map {{1, Foo::foo}};

int main()
{
    return Foo::foo;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o foo foo.cc
/tmp/ccZXCwiK.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
foo.cc:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `Foo::foo'
```

If I comment out the map, things link just fine.  Is this a compiler bug, or is it some corner case I am missing in the standard?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9da4dacc301287d

Comment: And again, a `+` magically fixes things: `static std::map<int, int> map {{1, +Foo::foo}};` works fine.

Comment: @DyP : Wow.  That's quite amazing and quite frightening.  I would never put that in my code because the comment I would have to add explaining why it was there would be worse than the "fix."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You forgot to *define* the static member.**

As soon as you *odr-use* it, a full definition is required. Yes, even though it has an inline initialiser and, yes, even though it's marked `constexpr`.

Add:

```
constexpr int Foo::foo;
```

- ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1081e7cef4f1aeb2))

Your original code works for me in GCC 4.8.1 via both [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/bfnzYG) and [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7c37fe34a90ad1b), but that's with optimisations turned on (so that constant is likely being supplanted for the symbol in each case). With optimisations off, [the error is reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9da4dacc301287d).

Comment: Interesting.  This came up in an instance where I was replacing a macro with a constexpr.  Figuring out where odr-use applies is definitely causing me to slip up.